# Failing to Set Input Box Values on Website

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

I have the following VBA code:

```vb
Sub OpenWebPage()

    Dim oIE As Object
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument, hDataManager As IHTMLElementCollection, hDropSelect
    Dim HWNDSrc As Long
    Dim itm As Variant


    'objects
    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


'//---Open the browser and log in, then navigate to the data manager
    oIE.silent = True 'No pop-ups
    oIE.Visible = True

    sURL = "https://publicisuk.lumina.mediaocean.com/Admin/DataManager.aspx"
    oIE.navigate sURL

    'wait for process to complete before executing the next task
    Do While oIE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until oIE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'get window ID for IE so we can set it as active window
    HWNDSrc = oIE.HWND
    'set IE as active window
    SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc

    'loop through elements/ items to find username field
    For Each itm In oIE.document.All
        If itm = "[object HTMLInputElement]" Then
            If itm.Name = "username" Then
                Debug.Print "Username field found!"
                itm.Value = "johnsmith@gmail.com"
                Debug.Print "Username: " & itm.Value
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next itm

    'now loop through to find password element
    For Each itm In oIE.document.All
        If itm = "[object HTMLInputElement]" Then
            If itm.Name = "password" Then
                Debug.Print "Password field found!"
                itm.Value = "IAmAMonkey"
                Debug.Print "Password: " & itm.Value
                Application.SendKeys "~", True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next itm
```

What it does is loads Internet Explorer to an object, and then navigates to a URL where I want to log in. I loop through the elements on the web-page checking for `InputElements`. When the `Username` input box is found it sets the `.Value` to the username, and when the `Password` input box is found it sets the `.Value` to the password, after which I send the `Enter` key, presumably to log in.

Now, the interesting problem. When I run this it prints out that it finds the respective fields, and also prints out their newly set values, **however**, no text appears in the boxes at all.

I have also tried the following syntax:

`oIE.Document.getElementById("username").Value = "johnsmith@gmail.com"`

`oIE.Document.getElementsByName("username").Value = "johnsmith@gmail.com"`

With the same result - there is no error, but the values aren't showing up in the boxes.

Does anyone know why this would be the case or what is wrong with my approach?

Below is the HTML code.

```html
<div id="login-panel">

            <input name="username" class="form-required-field" id="username" accesskey="u" type="text" placeholder="Username" value="" data-bind="value: form().username, placeholder: bundle['user.label.html']" htmlescape="true" autocomplete="off" cssclass="form-required-field"><!-- organization select goes here if multiple organizations use the same domain --><div class="inline-organization-panel" id="inline-organization-panel" style="display: none;" data-bind="moSlideVisible: isOrganisationSelectPanelVisible()">
                <span id="inline-organization-label" data-bind="text: bundle['organization.panel.label']">Choose organization.</span>
                <div data-bind="foreach: organisationInfoArray"></div>
            </div>

            <input name="password" class="form-required-field" id="password" accesskey="p" type="password" placeholder="Password" value="" data-bind="value: form().password, placeholder: bundle['password.label.html']" htmlescape="true" autocomplete="off" cssclass="form-required-field" csserrorclass="error"><!-- Continent selection goes here if mf-style username and don't have continent cookie -->
```

Comment: I get re-directed to pretty much this: https://publicisuk.lumina.mediaocean.com/mo-cas/login  Is this representative of the same issue?

Comment: Yes, so the reason for the initial address is after the login it will automatically move to the Data Manager. But it is still the same log in screen, yes.

Comment: Those two elements have event listeners. It is likely you need to find the right ones and attach/dispatch them in the right sequence on each node.

Comment: I have tried, and get a successful result.  I used `getElementByID`, but looped it until I was `not nothing` I think there is a script maybe slowing that site down as it's hit and miss.  Maybe worth looking at the IE loading of the site.  Ill put in an answer what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would focus on each element before assigning value then you simply need to remove the disabled attribute from the submit button

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub LogIn()
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://publicisuk.lumina.mediaocean.com/mo-cas/login"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document

            With .querySelector("#username")
                .Focus
                .Value = "johnsmith@gmail.com"
            End With
            With .querySelector("#password")
                .Focus
                .Value = "IAMaMonkey"
            End With
            With .querySelector("#buttonSignin")
                .removeAttribute "disabled"
                .Click
            End With
        End With

        Stop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @QHarr, that works perfectly. I have a few questions though. Obviously I don't have much understanding when it comes to HTML parsing, so what made you use `.querySelector`? Is that your default method, or was there something in the HTML code that made you use it? Also, why use `SHDocVw`?

Comment: .querySelector/querySelectorAll is for matching via [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) - it is faster, more flexible and more concise.  SHDocVw is just best practice to include the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is where I got to, i'll try again a little later, but may help in the meantime.

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim d As HTMLDocument
Dim f As HTMLFormElement

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = 1
ie.navigate "https://publicisuk.lumina.mediaocean.com/Admin/DataManager.aspx"

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set d = ie.document
Set f = d.forms(0)

'Putting a break point here and waiting a moment allows access

f.elements("username").Value = "username"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested and found that the code would run when setting breakpoints before setting value but wouldn't run without breakpoints.

I think it could be that debug mode adds more delay so I tried to add a separate delay in the code and it works. You could check my sample below:

```
Sub LOADIE()
    Set ieA = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ieA.Visible = True
    ieA.navigate "https://publicisuk.lumina.mediaocean.com/mo-cas/login"
    Do Until ieA.readyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop

    delay 4

    Set doc = ieA.Document
    Set UserName = doc.getElementById("username")
    UserName.Value = "johnsmith@gmail.com"
    Set Password = doc.getElementById("password")
    Password.Value = "IAmAMonkey"
    Set btn = doc.getElementById("buttonSignin")
    btn.Disabled = False
    btn.Click
End Sub

Private Sub delay(seconds As Long)
    Dim endTime As Date
    endTime = DateAdd("s", seconds, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```